# Issue when deploying a phoenix appwith Gigalixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gigalixir

I've followed the tutorial provided by the docs but I think I've got a problem with my node version when trying to deploying a phoenix app using distillery.
I get the following error:

```
remote:  Node 10.16.3
       Will export the following config vars:
       APP_NAME
       DATABASE_URL
       LIBCLUSTER_KUBERNETES_NODE_BASENAME
       LIBCLUSTER_KUBERNETES_SELECTOR
       POOL_SIZE
       PORT
       SECRET_KEY_BASE
       SOURCE_VERSION
       * MIX_ENV=prod

-----> Installing binaries
       clean_cache option set to true.
       Cleaning out cache contents
remote: ...
remote: ...
remote: mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/node-v10.16.3\r-linux-x64/*’: No such file or directory
remote: Deploy aborted
To https://git.gigalixir.com/alienated-neglected-asiansmallclawedotter.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.gigalixir.com/alienated-neglected-asiansmallclawedotter.git/
```

Any idea?

Comment: It looks like your node version has a `\r` at the end of it. Can you paste the output of `cat -v phoenix_static_buildpack.config`?

Comment: sashacode:/mnt/c/Users/Sandro/Desktop/Code/phoenix_apps/ssf_cube$ cat -v phoenix_static_buildpack.config
node_version=10.16.3^M
npm_version=6.9.0^M
clean_cache=true

Comment: I think the problem is those ^M characters. Try getting rid of them with http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-delete-m-character-in.html?m=1

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Thanks